# Doctrine: Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

When I execute my query it looks like this:

```
SELECT p FROM AppBundle\Entity\Shrubs p 

WHERE p.botanicalname LIKE :botanicalname 

AND p.commonname LIKE :commonname 

AND p.borderlinehardy = :x

ORDER BY p.commonname ASC
```

But I want the x to have quotation marks around it. In the query, I have that particular line like this:

```
andWhere("p.$key = :x")
```

But if I add single quotes around the x, I get the "Invalid parameter number" error. How do I put quotes around that x without getting the error?

EDIT: My entire query looks like this:

```
 $shrubs = $query
            ->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname', ':botanicalname'))
            ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%' . $botanicalname . '%')
            ->andwhere($query->expr()->like('p.commonname', ':commonname'))
            ->setParameter('commonname', '%' . $commonname . '%')
            ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC');

        $checkfor = array("wetsoil"=>"Tolerates Wet Soil",
            "borderlinehardy"=>"Borderline Hardy",
            "moistsoil"=>"Prefers Moist Soil",
            "peatysoil"=>"Prefers Peaty Soil",
            "welldrainedsoil"=>"Prefers Well-drained Soil",
            "drought"=>"Tolerates Drought",
            "claysoil"=>"Tolerates Clay Soil",
            "sandysoil"=>"Prefers Sandy Soil",
            "loamsoil"=>"Prefers Loam Soil",
            "infertilesoil"=>"Tolerates Infertile Soil",
            "richsoil"=>"Prefers Rich Soil",
            "compactedsoil"=>"Tolerates Compacted Soil",
            "cityconditions"=>"Tolerates City Conditions",
            "pollution"=>"Tolerates Pollution",
            "salt"=>"Tolerates Salt Conditions",
            "windy"=>"Tolerates Windy Conditions",
            "shade"=>"Prefers Shade",
            "partshade"=>"Prefers Part Shade",
            "fullsun"=>"Prefers Full Sun");

        reset($checkfor);

        foreach ($checkfor as $key => $value) {
            if (${$key} == "x") {
                $shrubs = $query->andWhere("p.$key = ':x'")
                    ->setParameter('x', $key)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can not use placeholder twice. Work with `andWhere("p.$key = :$key")`

Comment: And this `But I want the x to have quotation marks around it.` can not be done. Because prepared statements dont work that way. If you bind the param you say what type it is and rest is done internaly. Interger Type dont get qouts but Type String will.

Comment: If I try the first comment, I get the error: "Invalid parameter: token x is not defined in the query."

Comment: Second comment: the "x" is saved as a char in the database. Shouldn't that have quotes around it?

Comment: One big problem here is that we can not know what is accessed via `${$key}` and where these variables are created.

Comment: for _Invalid parameter_ `$query->andWhere("p.$key = :$key")->setParameter($key, $key)`

Comment: `quotes around it` as i sayed that does the api by itself, if here real prepared staments are used.

Comment: Still the same error. So frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the hole query for each call

```
$checkfor = array("wetsoil"=>"Tolerates Wet Soil",
            "borderlinehardy"=>"Borderline Hardy",
            "moistsoil"=>"Prefers Moist Soil",
            "peatysoil"=>"Prefers Peaty Soil",
            "welldrainedsoil"=>"Prefers Well-drained Soil",
            "drought"=>"Tolerates Drought",
            "claysoil"=>"Tolerates Clay Soil",
            "sandysoil"=>"Prefers Sandy Soil",
            "loamsoil"=>"Prefers Loam Soil",
            "infertilesoil"=>"Tolerates Infertile Soil",
            "richsoil"=>"Prefers Rich Soil",
            "compactedsoil"=>"Tolerates Compacted Soil",
            "cityconditions"=>"Tolerates City Conditions",
            "pollution"=>"Tolerates Pollution",
            "salt"=>"Tolerates Salt Conditions",
            "windy"=>"Tolerates Windy Conditions",
            "shade"=>"Prefers Shade",
            "partshade"=>"Prefers Part Shade",
            "fullsun"=>"Prefers Full Sun");

reset($checkfor);


foreach ($checkfor as $key => $value) {
      if (${$key} == "x") {
          //create for each call a full query , 
          //maybe you have not $this, then chnage it, 
          //but get a new instacne
          $query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
         //create 
         $shrubs = $query
            ->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname', ':botanicalname'))
            ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%' . $botanicalname . '%')
            ->andwhere($query->expr()->like('p.commonname', ':commonname'))
            ->setParameter('commonname', '%' . $commonname . '%')
            ->andWhere("p.$key = :$key")
            ->setParameter($key, $key)
            ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC')   
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
       }
 }
```

Comment: It still gives the exact same error! The query doesn't like those single quotes for some reason. It throws it off and can't correctly identity the parameters. Unbelievable

Comment: Then it that part of the query becomes: "p.borderlinehardy = :borderlinehardy" instead of "p.borderlinehardy = :x", so it still doesn't have the quotes around it.

Comment: How about doing just `->andWhere("p.$key = '$key'")` without setParameter ??